# Just installed LVM Raid 1 on a new server with 2x 10Tb hard drives and the Disk I/O is killing everything else every second

Tags: hard-drive, raid, lvm, io

I copied a bit of data on my LVM based RAID1 (not hardware RAID) with 2× 10Tb hard drives:

```
/dev/mapper/users-users  9.1T  1.9G  8.6T   1% /home
```

and now it's killing my I/O to the point where my mouse, keyboard, video are blocked/unblocked/blocked/unblocked...

I'm thinking that maybe something is wrong at the hardware level but wondering what that could be. Wondering what to test first to try to make a better diagnostic.

I have another 2 drives in the same drive array but they are not setup in RAID mode.

Looking at the output of `iotop` it tells me that there is about 2Mb/s written to disk, a pretty much permanent write... When I look at the Disk LED, I can see them come up and out over and over again and can hear the seeking heads too.

Trying to watch a video, it fails really bad. Choppy would not even be the 
word here. It's like one image every other second if even that much. So a really big I/O killer for the entire computer.

Wondering whether someone would have encountered such a problem before and what can be done to fix it if possible (I certainly hope it is possible!)

My motherboard is a Supermicro *X11DPH-T* and I also got a case from Supermicro the *745BAC-R1K28B2 4U Full Tower Chassis*. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The server is new and so is the install (i.e. not an upgrade from 16.04 or who knows what...)

Would there be a way to know whether a specific hard drive or some other hardware device is causing the trouble?

---

The output of free. I'm not swapping, I barely use the 512Gb of RAM.

```
$ free -m
            total      used      free    shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       515636      2676    510291       114        2668      509935
Swap:       30047         0     30047
```

And here is the output of `mdstat`. It looks normal from what I know of raid.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdf1[2] sde1[0]
      9766302720 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 4/73 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

As for the CPUs, it's 2× Xeon Silver 4216. That's 16 Core/CPU and I currently have Hyperthreading turned on so it looks like 64 CPUs.

Comment: What's the output of `free -m`? What's the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`? Which CPU's do you have? [Edit] your question with this information.

Comment: @vidarlo I made the update. As a side note, using an SSH connection, the computer is lightning fast. Not useful to make use of it as a desktop though. Even a `find /home` (which is the RAID).

Comment: @vidarlo Well! I found "the fix". I thought it would be the LVM RAID1 because that's what I just did change (at least though I thought) but in reality the Gnome Settings had something to do with it. Completely resetting though fixed the problem. So it is a form of software display _feature_ which grossly fails on my computer.